# I18n.t(:child2) reference issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, ruby-on-rails-6

How do I reference a child2 of parent2 using I18n.t(:child2)?

I get an error:

> => "translation missing: en.child2"

```
en:
  parent1:
    child1: 
      child2:child2
  parent2:
    child1: 
      child2:child2
  parent3:
    child1: 
      child2:child2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference it as a String.

```
I18n.t("parent1.child1.child2")
```